# CompileAssemblyFromSource comments

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, code-generation

my c# script contains some fields with commetns ,
when i use the CodeDomProvider to compile it , everything is great
but when i look at the code i see there is no comments included

thats my code:

```
CodeDomProvider codeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");           
System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
parameters.OutputAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "myFile.dll";

CompilerResults results = codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, "Some C# code with documentation");
```

Comment: Are you expecting a .xml file with XML comments? It's not clear what you mean.

Comment: im getting just the code without my comments above some code lines

Comment: Well you're getting an *assembly* - assemblies don't have comments. That has nothing to do with compiling it within code, it's just the nature of assemblies. If you were looking for XML comments, that would be a different matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get non-XML comments anyway - they're never part of the result of compilation. However, you can generate the XML documentation file using the `CompilerOptions` property to just pass a command-line parameter to the compiler:

```
parameters.CompilerOptions = "/doc:myFile.xml";
```

So if you have code like this:

```
/// <summary>This will be included in myFile.xml</summary>
public class Foo
{
    // This will not, as it's not an XML comment.
}
```

Comment: i'll be able to use it as intellisense?

Comment: @roy.d: Yes. That's how Intellisense picks up documentation comments - from an XML file with the same base name as the assembly. But those won't be "comments above some code lines" - they'll be XML comments before *declarations*.

Comment: i managed to save the doc, when it local run my file locate at iisexpress where and how can i manage this file?

Comment: @roy.d: I have no idea what you mean by "my file locate at iisexpress" - but you can specify a fully-qualified path in the options, if that's what you're after. (It doesn't help that we really have no idea what you're trying to achieve.)

Comment: @roy.d: Well look at the code I've given - it's specifying a filename already. Just change that to be a fully-qualified path. You'll need to add double-quotes if you need spaces in the path; I'd try to avoid that if possible.

Comment: i didnt get what you mean "You'll need to add double-quotes if you need spaces in the path;" but i need space in my path :) example will be great

Comment: Something like `parameters.CompilerOptions = "/doc:\"c:\\Some Path\\foo.xml\"";` Note that the backslashes and quotes need to be escaped like that because they're in a C# string literal.